# ASA 5540 v8.4(3) vpn to ASA 5505 v8.2(5), tunnel up but I cant ping from 5505 to IP on other side

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, ping

I am having problems pinging from a 5505(remote) to IP 10.160.70.10 in the network behind the 5540(HQ side).

5505
inside IP: 10.56.0.1
Out: 71.43.109.226

5540
Inside: 10.1.0.8
out: 64.129.214.27

I Can ping from 5540 to 5505 inside 10.56.0.1.
I also ran ASDM packet tracer in both directions, it is ok from 5540 to 5505, but drops the packet from 5505 to 5540.
It gets through the ACL and dies at the NAT.

Here is the 5505 config, I am sure it is something simple I am missing.

```
ASA Version 8.2(5) 
!
hostname ASA-CITYSOUTHDEPOT
domain-name rngint.net
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.56.0.1 255.255.0.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 71.43.109.226 255.255.255.252 
!
banner motd ***ASA-CITYSOUTHDEPOT***
banner asdm CITY SOUTH DEPOT ASA5505
ftp mode passive
clock timezone EST -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name rngint.net
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip host 71.43.109.226 host 10.1.0.125 
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.106.70.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.106.130.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip host 71.43.109.226 host 10.160.70.10 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip host 71.43.109.226 host 10.1.0.125 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.106.130.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.106.70.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip host 71.43.109.226 10.106.70.0 255.255.255.0 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging buffer-size 25000
logging buffered informational
logging asdm warnings
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
icmp permit any inside
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_nat0_outbound
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 71.43.109.225 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa-server TACACS+ protocol tacacs+
aaa-server TACACS+ (inside) host 10.106.70.36
 key *****
aaa authentication http console LOCAL 
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
aaa authorization exec authentication-server
http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
http 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 inside
http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside
snmp-server host inside 10.106.70.7 community *****
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server community *****
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_1_cryptomap
crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs group1
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer 64.129.214.27 
crypto map outside_map 1 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 1
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash md5
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 inside
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
management-access inside
dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 10.56.0.100-10.56.0.121 inside
dhcpd dns 10.1.0.125 interface inside
dhcpd auto_config outside interface inside
!
dhcprelay server 10.1.0.125 outside
dhcprelay enable inside
dhcprelay setroute inside
dhcprelay timeout 60

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
tftp-server inside 10.1.1.25 CITYSOUTHDEPOT-ASA-Confg
webvpn
tunnel-group 64.129.214.27 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 64.129.214.27 ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *****
!
!
prompt hostname context
```

Comment: I think your missing some cryptomap entries

Comment: But my vpn tunnel is up and passing traffic. I just cant ping 10.160.70.10 from the 5505.

Comment: Could same-security-traffic be of use - http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/command/reference/cmd_ref/s1.html

Comment: Some more information.  I can ping the 10.1.0.125 and traceroute resolves it.  Oh the IP I put in above that I cant get to is a typo, the address is 10.106.70.10.

Comment: From my VPN experience so far I know that the cryptomap acl's should match....Correct?                  Here are the crypto acl's from both sides.

Comment: 5505 access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip host 71.43.109.226 host 10.1.0.125 
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.106.70.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.106.130.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip host 71.43.109.226 host 10.160.70.10

Comment: 5540 access-list CRYPTO_ACL extended permit ip 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 object CitySouthPIX 
access-list CRYPTO_ACL extended permit ip 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 
access-list CRYPTO_ACL extended permit ip 10.106.70.0 255.255.255.0 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0 
access-list CRYPTO_ACL extended permit ip 10.106.130.0 255.255.255.0 10.56.0.0 255.255.0.0     Keep in mind the VPN tunnel IS UP.

Comment: Possible fix......Ok so the 5505 can ping 10.1.0.125 but not 10.106.70.10.   In the 5505 I added the following (which was incorrect) access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip host 71.43.109.226 host 10.160.70.10-----------I am going to change it to this (so it will now be correct) access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip host 71.43.109.226 host 10.106.70.10---------------Anyone think this will do it?

Comment: Also this line is also in the 5505, which is why I think this will fix it------access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip host 71.43.109.226 host 10.1.0.125

Comment: It looks like this is an asymmetric routing issue.  does anyone know how to exclude a certain static route from being redistributed into eigrp?